# Create round corner for a div

Tags: css, html

I want to create a html based chart like below , not sure how to proceed

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is `border-radius` ie

```css
.inner {
  background: #FFB6C1;
  width: 40px;
  height:20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.outter {
  width:100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outter">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: the only problem is when the inner is so small then the radius will break

https://jsfiddle.net/z124ey03/

Comment: Use `overflow:hidden;` on the outer div.